# Fetch sorted ArrayList from local DB of Realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I am getting a list of objects from api and storing that list in local DB using `Realm`. I am able to store and fetch the data. But while I am fetching the data from realm DB the order of objects in list are not same as the list coming from api. I am sharing the code snippet

```
fun insertStatuses(statuses: List<Eis>) {
    realm.executeTransaction { transaction ->
        statuses.forEach { eis->
            transaction.insertOrUpdate(eis)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
fun fetchAllStatuses(): RealmResults<Eis>? {
    return realm.where<Status>().findAll()
}
```

---

```
mViewModel?.fetchAllStatuses()?.let { results ->
     status.clear()
     status.addAll(realm.copyFromRealm(results))
     statusAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

**Edit**

I have also tried to add one field in model class which will hold the api index still no effect

```
fun insertStatuses(eises: List<Eis>) {
    realm.executeTransaction { transaction ->
        eises.forEachIndexed { index, eis ->
            Log.d("eis_index_value", index.toString())
            Log.d("eis_index_value", eis.name)
            val mEis = Eis()
            mEis.apply {
                eisApiPosition = index + 1
                Log.d("eis_index_position", eisApiPosition.toString())
                _id = eis._id
                name = eis.name
                transaction.insertOrUpdate(this)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Log is printing the correct value but while I fetched those objects then the `index` value is messed up in every object.
Can anyone help me to fix this issue

Comment: Realm does not guarantee an order when reading into a Results object. You need to specify a property to order by. List objects within a realm object always maintain their order.

Comment: @Jay I have also tried adding an extra value to model class which holds the index of object from api, while inserting in DB the index was correctly printed in log but while I fetch from DB those are messed up with duplicate index mostly 0.

Comment: Well, converting an Int to a String is going to cause issues. If you have the following ints converted to strings "0",  "1",  "2",  "3", "10", "30", "4" and then you order them, they will sort lexicographically - "0", "1", "10", "2", "3", "30", "4". If you want numerical order, leave the Ints as Ints, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 30.  If that doesn't fix it, can you also *edit your question* to include your Realm model(s) and include the code you use to load them into a Results, sorted?

Comment: `eisApiPosition` is an Int value, but I think the problem is in somewhere else. I have inspected the realm DB it was saving the value correctly at initial stage but somehow it got changed in somewhere @Jay thanks